# How to get two attributes of a model in the same HTML file

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

#### Code

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/cars", params = "request")
public String showSomeAmountCars(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {
    String count = request.getParameter("count");
    int parsedCount = Integer.parseInt(count);
    model.addAttribute("someCars", carService.getCars(parsedCount));

    return "cars";
}
```

- In the method `showSomeAmountCars` I get some number of cars using parameter in URL link.
- In the method `showAllCars` I get the whole list of cars.

#### Expected behavior

- if I request `/cars`, then I get the list of cars from the HTML file
- if I request `/cars?count = 2`, then I get the list of two cars from the same HTML file

#### Question

How can I get the two added attributes in the HTML file and make sure they don't conflict?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an optional request parameter like this:

```
@GetMapping("/cars")
public String showSomeAmountCars(@RequestParam(name = "cars", required = false) Integer count, Model model) {


   if( count == null ) {
     model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getCars());
   } else {
     model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getCars(count));
   }
    return "cars";
}
```